# How to call a category with a single morphism between every two objects?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

How to call a category where for every pair of objects $A, B$, there is a unique morphism $f\colon A\to B$?  (A *trivial category*?)

Comment: A boring category?

Comment: I wouldn't know if there's an official name, but it is defined analogously to a complete graph. However, "complete category" means something different :)

Comment: @AdLibitum, you do not call a group with a single element a boring group.

Comment: @Alexey I generally call trivial things boring.

Comment: @Alexey: No. Yet it is pretty boring, isn't it?

Comment: @AdLibitum i would never call a trivial group or the empty set boring.

Comment: @AdLibitum, i think that [*chaotic category*](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/chaotic+category) (see the answer of Martin Brandenburg) sounds better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These categories are called [indiscrete](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/indiscrete+category).

Comment: Of course, "indiscrete" started off as a pun on "indiscreet". Some argue that it's a bad pun and that we should say "codiscrete" instead. E.g. [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/codiscrete+object).